# How to get the IDs of all documents in a collection using firestore REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If I have a path like `collection1 > document 1> collection2 > document2`, can I get only the IDs of all the documents in `collection1`?

For a simple case like `collection > document`, a GET request with  `mask.fieldPaths="__name__"` gives me the ID `document`. But for the nested collection above, I get empty JSON if I ask for the ID `document1` in `collection1`.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to know things about the documents in collection1 while querying collection2?  You can only query one collection at a time, and it doesn't matter how they are nested.  A nested subcollection is completely independent from any parent collections when it comes to query results.

Comment: @DougStevenson No, I am not querying collection2. I am only querying collection1. If a document in collection1 has no collections but only fields, my GET request will give me all the documents. But because document1 has collection2, querying collection1 does not return anything.

Comment: That shouldn't affect the results. Please edit the question to show a test scenario with actual data and query that you're using.  We should be able to reproduce the problem using the information you provide.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to update the question.

Comment: It sounds a bit like `document 1` may be non-existent. If you have no `document 1` document, but there **is** a subcollection under it, the Firestore console will show `document 1` in italtics to indicate that and show a label explaining this in the bottom right of the panel.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes that is what is happening! But could you tell me why? I created those documents via a POST request. There was no error.

Comment: Maybe you would like to, again, show the code or queries you ran that duplicates the results?  We can't see anything that you've done so we don't know what we're looking at. It's just all guessing at this point.

Comment: I sounds like you created documents in the subcollection, but that doesn't automatically create parent documents. You will need to create those with an explicit API call to be able to get those documents from the API call.